# Substract MS-Access Query's Column Value From Other Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a problem. I want to substract query's column value by using value from other query's column.

**TABLE STOCK**

```
ITEM  BOX  PLASTIC  
ABC     2      0  
DEF     0     15  
GHI     1      5  
JKL     0     10
```

**TABLE DAMAGED STOCK**

```
ITEM  BOX  PLASTIC  
DEF    0     15  
GHI    1      0  
JKL    0      5
```

**EXPECTED RESULT (READY STOCK)**

```
ITEM  BOX  PLASTIC  
ABC     2      0   
GHI     0      5  
JKL     0      5
```

I have try using NOT IN SQL Statement but that only able to hide same value for all 3 column.

What SQL Statement suitable to substract each column value and not showing any records if both BOX & PLASTIC are zero.

Comment: I am unclear on what you mean by _"and not showing any records if both BOX & PLASTIC are zero."_. Is that **after** you've done the subtraction, or based on the existing values in the tables? What I see in the example tables and what you expect, it doesn't make sense. For example, none of them have 0 for Box **AND** 0 for Plastic, so why aren't all of them in the expected result table?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english @Brien. What i mean, the expected result should only contain ITEM which have available BOX & PLASTIC. For example item DEF

Comment: that’s ok, I understand. I understand your question now. The reason `DEF` is not in the list is because all `15` Plastic are damaged, so zero are left. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the `left join` to check the availability

```
select s.ITEM, IIF(s.box-ds.box is null, s.box, s.box-ds.box) BOX,
               IIF(s.plastic-ds.plastic is null, s.plastic, s.plastic-ds.plastic) PLASTIC  
from STOCK s
left join DAMAGEDSTOCK ds on ds.item = s.item
where IIF(s.box-ds.box is null, 1, s.box-ds.box) <> 0 OR
      IIF(s.plastic-ds.plastic is null, 1, s.plastic-ds.plastic) <> 0
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. You make my day @yogesh-sharma ^_^